# Hiding overlapping panels in design mode

Tags: wpf

I have 4 Panels that should be shown/hidden based on 4 radio buttons being checked.
only a single panel will be shown at a time.
all 4 panels need to be shown in the same position (within the same grid cell)

The problem is, once all 4 panels are put in the same grid cell, the panels are overlapped and 
difficult to do changes to any specific panel in design mode.

Is there any way that we can hide the panels in design mode so that i can work on a single panel at a time?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no notebook control that you can just hide the tabs of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to create a UserControl for each panel, and display the UserControl instead of the Panel.  You can then edit each UserControl by independently.

There is a pretty straightforward tutorial here - http://www.longhorncorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/WPFUserControl09012008000033AM/WPFUserControl.aspx.